# Adding error message to google recaptcha in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using https://github.com/appleboy/CodeIgniter-reCAPTCHA library in my project. I want to add error message to my form when the recaptcha is not entered or invalid recaptcha...

for other fields i set like this...

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('txtPassword', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');
$this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', '%s: should have %s characters');
```

but in recaptcha no name... so no idea how to display a validation error when verification fails...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the documentation,

```
$recaptcha = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');
$response = $this->recaptcha->verifyResponse($recaptcha);
```

The `$response` parameter will either return `true` or `false`. You can either use session flashdata from using the [codeigniter documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html)

Or if you want to stick to form-validation for codeigniter, here's how you do it.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('g-recaptcha-response', 'recaptcha validation', 'required|callback_validate_captcha');
$this->form_validation->set_message('validate_captcha', 'Please check the the captcha form');
```

You would need to create a method validate_captcha which will make a file_get_contents call to the captcha api and based on it will return true or false.

```
function validate_captcha() {
    $captcha = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');
     $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=your secret key here &response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if ($response . 'success' == false) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.